# JQM works on desktop browser not mobile

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile

The following code works as expected on the various desktop browsers, however its target goal is oveasly a smartphone. when accessed from iPhone - content is blank under `<ul>`?

json is pulled from php page and works as expected.

EDITED: changed `getJSON` to static json `var info` for testing - still not rendered on mobile phone? - also tried various version of JQuery and JQuery-Mobile still no change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<link href="http://jqmdesigner.appspot.com/gk/lib/jquery.mobile/1.4.2/flatui/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<title>parse JSON</title>

<script>        

var info = [
{
"UID":5665,
"StudentID":"BA1400",
"LastName":"BARNES",
"FirstName":"JOHN",
"Affiliation":"DFRS"},
{"UID":10430,
"StudentID":"BA3700",
"LastName":"Barnyard",
"FirstName":"Ashley",
"Affiliation":"OTHER"},
{"UID":5781,
"StudentID":"BJ9188",
"LastName":"BARCLAY",
"FirstName":"GEOFFREY",
"Affiliation":"DFRS"},
{"UID":14815,
"StudentID":"BT0021",
"LastName":"Barhydt",
"FirstName":"Jimmy",
"Affiliation":"TAKOMA PARK"
}
];


$(document).on("pageinit", "#info-page", function () {

var server_url = "http://myDomain/tt_json.php"; 

$.getJSON(server_url, function(notUsing){
    var li = "";
    $.each(info, function (i, name) {
        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + name.LastName + ',  ' + name.FirstName + '</a></li>';
    });
    $("#prof-list").append(li).promise().done(function () {
        $(this).on("click", ".info-go", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#details-page").data("info", info[this.id]);
            $.mobile.changePage("#details-page");
        });

        $(this).listview("refresh");
    });
});
}); 

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#details-page", function () {
    var info = $(this).data("info");
    var info_view = "";t
    for (var key in info) {

        info_view += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a"><div class="ui-bar field" style="font-weight : bold; text-align: left;">' + key + '</div></div><div class="ui-block-b"><div class="ui-bar value" style="width : 75%">' + info[key] + '</div></div></div>';
    }
    $(this).find("[data-role=content]").html(info_view);
});

</script>
</head>

<body>          

<!--first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="info-page">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
     <h1>GET JSON data</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="prof-list" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b" role="heading">Names</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!--second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="details-page">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go back</a>
     <h1>User Details</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content"></div>
</div>          

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that the real server url in the code? That would not work in deployment. Maybe your desktop has some configuration that can resolve your url? Is the server running locally? For deployment you'd need something like "http://www.mywebsite.com/tt_json.php"

Comment: no - i removed actual url for security - code is fine in safari desktop browser - but no data on iPhone just html?

Comment: also tried iOS7 user agent in desktop browser, renders fine.

Comment: Changed the `getJSON` to static json `var info` for testing, again works on desktop but not on mobile browser???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this resolves the issue since i'm doing a standard json request from same domain but it did fix the issue:

added header:
    `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`